# Printing list in ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml

I would write (for debugging) a printer for a list of `((string * string) * 'a)`

I tried with:

```
(* print a list of ((string * string) * 'a)  *)
let rec print_list = function
[] -> Printf.printf "\n empty list \n %!"; ()
| ((s1,s2),a)::l -> Printf.printf "\n(s1,s2)= %s %s  \n %!" s1 s2; print_list l;;
```

but it doesn't print anything.

It should print at least `empty list`, right?

Comment: What does not work. Your approach is printing the reversed list.

Comment: it doesn't compile at all. It says that '(' ')' are unexpected but I thought it should be correct. I'm very new to ocaml

Comment: On Ocaml 4.01 it does compile successfully.

Comment: It does compile. If something isn't working for you, **copy-paste** the actual code that's not working, and the error message.

Comment: try `let print_list = print`

Comment: you are right, sorry. I pasted the wrong code, it just doesn't print anything. I've edited my question.

Comment: Start again a fresh toplevel.

Comment: did you actually print something? like `print_list []`

Comment: where did you try this code?

Answer (score 1):

In many languages (C and Ocaml) you'll better put the `\n` at *end* of `printf` format control string, or force the stdout to be flushed. Output to stdout is usually [buffered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer) (for performance reasons).

You should read the [documentation of Ocaml](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/) before coding in Ocaml.

You may also want to call (from [Pervasives](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html)) `print_newline`; read carefully documentation of [`Printf` module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Printf.html); you could end your `printf` format string with `%!`

Here is an example (copied from your edited question) with Ocaml 4.01:

```
% ocaml
    OCaml version 4.01.0

 # (* print a list of ((string * string) * 'a)  *)
 let rec print_list = function
   [] -> Printf.printf "\n empty list \n %!"; ()
   | ((s1,s2),a)::l -> Printf.printf "\n(s1,s2)= %s %s  \n %!" s1 s2; 
                       print_list l;;    

val print_list : ((string * string) * 'a) list -> unit = <fun>

# print_list [];;

empty list 
- : unit = ()
#
```

As you can see, `empty list`  gets printed. In the above code, `%`  is a shell prompt, `#` is an ocaml toplevel prompt. Your function is copied verbatim. `print_list [];;` is input at toplevel.

Comment: I have added both `\n` and `%!` at the end, but nothing changed. `%!` should flush output buffer, right?

Comment: everyone else can get this to work fine, there must be something else wrong in what you are doing.

Comment: the problem was that vim created a conflict file that overrides my edits during compiling, so that function was never called.. I appreciated and upvoted your answer, but I don't know if it is correct to accept it